# I didn't see him / I haven't seen him

Tags: present-perfect

Watching a movie, I've just heard of this lines:

> A: "I'm just looking for Barbie. Is he around?"
>
> B: "I haven't seen him."

I've always been confused about present perfect and simple past.
So why did B say so, not "I didn't see him." What's the difference?

<sup>The dialogue appears to be from the first episode of [Under the Dome](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1553656/) and "Barbie" is the nickname for a male character named Dale 'Barbie' Barbara.</sup>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*I haven't seen him*

means, essentially, I have not seen him *recently*.

*I didn't see him*

means, I did not see him *at some particular time*.

When the "particular time" ***is*** recently, the two can be used almost interchangeably:

> "Have you seen Bob around?"
>   "No, I haven't seen him."
>
> "Did you see Bob just walk by here?"
>   "No, I didn't see him."

Other times, though, there are clearer dividing lines between when to use *didn't see* instead of *haven't seen*:

> "Have you seen Mr. Hernandez go into Mrs. Olson's house?"
>   "Yes, I have seen that many times."
>
> "On the night of the murder, did you see Mr. Hernandez go into Mrs. Olson's house?"
>   "Yes, I did see that."

The first question refers to a more open-ended span of time, while the second refers to a very specific time segment.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, *did* is past and this means that some time in past, the answerer has not seen Barbie.

Using *have* extends the time from past into the present. *I haven't seen...* here means till the time the sentence is spoken, the answerer has not seen Barbie.